# How to embed my webiste Header(logo, menu) for each of my panel variant

Tags: panels, theming

I'am using Panel and I created several variant for many content type.

Is there a way to add my Top WebSite Header composed with (Logo, Main Menu, Second Menu, Search textbox, Language switcher and social network Icon) for each of my variant in a desired region.

Here is what I would like to do.

Create a kind of template called MyHeader where I would put any html element that I need for my Website Header(Logo, menu etc...).
If it's possible to create a template for MyHeader, how to do that ?

Use MyHeader into each variant panel, I would like to drag it into a specific Region , like dragging a simple widget.

Is it possible to do this.?

Note: I'm using Omega 4 as base theme for my subtheme

Sory for my english.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a block with the required Header and then assign that to your content regions in panels. I think that should be it.

And yes, you can theme your block as required using `block--block--[block-id].tpl.php` templates.